# Are there any Azure computer vision api rate limits?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

If so, what are the limits?  Do the CV api calls block or error if rate limit exceeded?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the plan you choose for your computer vision resource.

If you are using the Free instance, you can do 20 requests per minute. And if you are using the standard plan you can send 10 requests per second.

You can find more detail here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/computer-vision/

Answer (score 2):

From the [Optical Character Recognition (OCR) documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text):

> The free tier limits the request rate to 20 calls per minute. The paid
> tier allows 10 requests per second (RPS) that can be increased upon
> request. Use the Azure support channel or your account team to request
> a higher request per second (RPS) rate.

So, the limit of 10 requests per second can be changed.

> Do the CV api calls block or error if rate limit exceeded?

Yes. It returns `429 Too Many Requests` HTTP Status Code on requests to start an analysis.

**Obs:** I would like just to make an important observation, that should be on documentation but isn't: Those limits include **all requests for that endpoint**.

So when you execute a first request sending the image to be processed, and execute another one to know if its analysis result is ready, that counts like 2 requests.

*It could be obvious, but not to me. I first thought that only requests to "start" the analysis were limited, and requests to get the status of the analysis won't be counted. It broke my code and I could not understand why, until realize it...*

Comment: This seems like a big limitation. How do you overcome this? Did you have to write code to control the rate of calling the Azure API?

Comment: @KJAng Yes I did. But I also got in touch with Azure support, and they rise the limits to operational values to my application.

Comment: @KJAng About the limitation, I agree, but there is some logic to it. Without it, would be fairly easy to create a lot of accounts and execute a DoS attack.

Comment: Note theres no cost in having an account. You can provision multiple accounts and round robin the api keys